# Node.js sendFile image with CSS

Tags: css, node.js

I send image with sendFile in Node.js:

```
app.get('/logo', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `./images/logo.png`));
})
```

and I need to join CSS:

```
image {margin: auto, width: 500px, height: 500px};
```

Something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
app.get('/logo', function(req, res) {
    res.write('<style>image {margin: auto, width: 500px, height: 500px};</style>')
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `./images/logo.png`));
})
```

Comment: You should just be doing this using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` for static serving and place your `/images` and `/css` under `public` in your application root.

Comment: Ok, I created structure:
...
public
 - images
 -- logo.png
 - css
 -- style.css
...

but how can I link page with logo.png and style.css?

Comment: wut... join css? send image? css + an image? something is... seriously wrong here. you can't have a route that returns both an image and some css and expect it to work well. It could certainly return both in one response body, but the client wouldn't what to do with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two different routes. One to serve the HTML/CSS and the other to serve the actual image:

```
app.get('/logo', function(request, response) {
  res.end('<img src="/logo.png" style="margin: auto, width: 500px, height: 500px"/>');
})

app.get('/logo.png', function(request, response) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './images/logo.png'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I call route '/logo', there is only CSS. If I call route 'logo.png', there is image without styles. Do you know, how to combine this two routes?

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)